# Angular js not finding controller?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using angular js, I have written code in two different jsp files.showing two different views.
if I render single view it works fine.but if I render both views on same page I got this error

`Error: Argument 'UserCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`

the js code snippet in jsp's is as follows.

in my first jsp file is

```
// Bootstrap the Application
var App = angular.module('module', []);
// Set up a controller and define a model
App.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    jQuery.get("<c:url value='${someUrl}'/>",
            function(data) {
            angular.element('#user_detail').scope().user = data;
            angular.element('#user_detail').scope().$apply();
}, "json");
});
```

and in the second one is

```
// Bootstrap the Application
var App = angular.module('module', []);

// Set up a controller and define a model
App.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.profile = {};
    jQuery.get("<c:url value='${someUrl}'/>",
            function(data) {
            angular.element('#profile').scope().profile = data;
            angular.element('#profile').scope().$apply();
}, "json");
});
```

I tried giving distinct names to modules but that too did not worked for me.any help is appreciated.
thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

got it worked. It was due to the ng-app variable, i have binded it on both jsp pages.So now i binded it to the main body wrapper for both the jsp's.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are reintializing the app variable pls try below code

```
 var App  = App  ||angular.module('module', []);
```

working fiddle is 
 http://jsfiddle.net/e6A5q/

Comment: thanks for the reply but the issue was something else, have described it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a double instantiation of my app in two separate files.